# Cannot calling attribute declared in constructor from method of class

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, nodes

I have an `HomeController` which has the method index. I have declared this.data variable in constructor. when i calling this.data in index method i got an error with message like

TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

This `HomeController`:

```
import Controller from "./../../vendor/controller";
import * as express from "express";
import hException from "./../helper/exception.helper";

class HomeController extends Controller {
    data:object
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.data = {
            tes: 'tes'
        }
    }
    async index(request:express.Request, response:express.Response, next:express.NextFunction):Promise<any>{
        try {
            let template =  'home/index';
            //next to viewer
            response.render(template, { layout: 'dashboard', data: this.data});
        } catch (error) {
            next(new hException(error))
        }
    }
}

export default HomeController
```

`Routes` that calling `HomeController`:

```
import * as express from "express";
import Controller from "./../../controller/home.controller";

import { Jwt as MJwt } from "./../../middleware/auth.middleware";

class Routes {
    private router:express.Router = express.Router()
    private path:string = '/'
    private controller:Controller
    private MJwt = new MJwt()
    constructor() {
        this.controller = new Controller;
        this.run()
    }

    public run(){
        this.router.route(this.path)
            .get(
                this.controller.index
            );
    }
}

export default Routes
```

Comment: Try this `this.controller.index()`. Add parenthesis

Comment: @DaniyalLukmanov got an another error, i need req, res, and next func from express

Comment: You should give more info on how do you use that route. And when you want to get a result using `async` you must add `await` to handle a promise.

Comment: @DaniyalLukmanov I am using route with calling a class of Controller, if u see class Routes in run() method of Routes class i am using the controller as middleware of express, method index() of HomeController still not calling another async promise why i should using await?, i just calling object that has been declared in HomeController constructor, and calling it in method of thats own class.

Comment: You should provide arguments to the `index` method `request, response, next`. And that method returns promise, so you should use `await`.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has solved with declared the method of `HomeController` with `arrow function` [link](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/arrow-function) for details. or using binding function [link](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/this-is-why-we-need-to-bind-event-handlers-in-class-components-in-react-f7ea1a6f93eb/) for details.

[Solved with arrow function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbJj3.png)